# 404 response calling post method in spring controller

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

I have some strange problem with Spring controller and ajax. Controller method returns 404 when I try to pass JSON object to it, using ajax.

This is my code:

```
@Data
@Builder
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Car {
    private int gears;
    private String color;
}

@Slf4j
@RestController
public class Test {

    @PostMapping("/ajaxJsonPost")
    public @ResponseBody HttpEntity<Car> samochod(@RequestBody Car car) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(Car.builder().color(car.getColor()).gears(car.getGears()).build(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxJsonPost", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public HttpEntity<Car> samochod() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(Car.builder().color("blue").gears(1).build(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And I send ajax with python code:

```
def main():
    app_url = 'http://localhost:8888/ajaxJsonPost'

    session = requests.Session()
    data = {'car': {'gears': 1,
                    'color': 'blue'}}
    response = session.post(url=app_url, data=data)
    # response = session.get(url=app_url)
    print(response)
    print(response.content)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the context of you application to the ajax call

```
def main():
    app_url = 'http://localhost:8888/YOUR_APP_CONTEXT/ajaxJsonPost'
```

Comment: I don't understand it. How should I do it? Where should I set it?

Comment: I add in properties `server.contextPath=/main/` but it still does not work.